# Error while converting a .mat file into csv file

Tags: excel, matlab, csv

I have used :

```matlab
load('feature_table.mat');
csvwrite('ft.csv',feature_table);
```

But it shows following error. How can I solve this?

```
Check for missing argument or incorrect argument data type in call to 
function 'real'.

Error in csvwrite (line 47)
throw(e)
```

More information about the file: The feature_table is a 3240x26 table

Comment: It is nice, if you write 1-2 sentences as an introduction

Comment: use [`writetable`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html) rather than `csvwrite`. This may solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem is, but Matlab recommends to use the "writematrix" function instead. See https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writematrix.html

You could also try saving the table as a .txt file, that is the output the Matlab website uses in their example of the csvwrite function (https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvwrite.html).

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer, if you are "not sure what the problem is" then you shouldn't be writing an answer, at best it is noise, at worst it will be wrong once the question is clarified...